Adding new drive to mdadm 6 array. - dn does not have a valid v1.2 superblock
I've stumbled upon and issue where I have an existing mdadm 6 array and I want to extend it with additional HDD to increase the capacity. I've done this before, but now I am failing on step 1 - add drive to mdadm array.
cat /proc/mdstat:
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid1] [raid0] [raid10] 
md150 : active raid1 sdj[1] sdk[0]
      1953382464 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 8/15 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid6 sde[17] sdc[13] sdi[16] sda[9] sdh[11] sdg[12] sdd[14] sdf[15] sdb[10]
      68364158464 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [9/9] [UUUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/10 pages [0KB], 524288KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

We are talking about md1.
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Jun 10 18:23:07 2021
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 68364158464 (63.67 TiB 70.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 9766308352 (9.10 TiB 10.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 9
     Total Devices : 9
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Jul 29 10:42:26 2024
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 9
   Working Devices : 9
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : exaria:1  (local to host exaria)
              UUID : 90f5737d:7389d4cb:7ddd2f9b:d0124c63
            Events : 193294

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      17       8       64        0      active sync   /dev/sde
      13       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
      14       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
      16       8      128        3      active sync   /dev/sdi
      11       8      112        4      active sync   /dev/sdh
      12       8       96        5      active sync   /dev/sdg
       9       8        0        6      active sync   /dev/sda
      15       8       80        7      active sync   /dev/sdf
      10       8       16        8      active sync   /dev/sdb

The drives are all the same (same model, size, etc). smartctl check is clear. blockdev --getsize64 shows the same number for random existing disk in the array and the new I want to add.
So finally - When I run mdadm /dev/md1 -a /dev/sdn I get mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdn as 18: Invalid argument
When I look into dmesg, I get (with relevant part of adding the drive):
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] mpt3sas_cm0: handle(0x16) sas_address(0x56c92bf00041d0ee) port_type(0x1)
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] scsi 0:0:12:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC  WUS721010AL W9G0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] scsi 0:0:12:0: SATA: handle(0x0016), sas_addr(0x56c92bf00041d0ee), phy(14), device_name(0x0000000000000000)
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] scsi 0:0:12:0: enclosure logical id (0x56c92bf00041d0e0), slot(2) 
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] scsi 0:0:12:0: enclosure level(0x0001), connector name(     )
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] scsi 0:0:12:0: atapi(n), ncq(y), asyn_notify(n), smart(y), fua(y), sw_preserve(y)
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] scsi 0:0:12:0: qdepth(32), tagged(1), scsi_level(7), cmd_que(1)
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: Attached scsi generic sg15 type 0
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: [sdn] 19532873728 512-byte logical blocks: (10.0 TB/9.10 TiB)
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: [sdn] 4096-byte physical blocks
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024]  end_device-0:1:6: add: handle(0x0016), sas_addr(0x56c92bf00041d0ee)
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: [sdn] Write Protect is off
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: [sdn] Mode Sense: 9b 00 10 08
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: [sdn] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[Mon Jul 29 10:01:50 2024] sd 0:0:12:0: [sdn] Attached SCSI disk
[Mon Jul 29 10:02:06 2024] md: sdn does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
[Mon Jul 29 10:02:06 2024] md: md_import_device returned -22

I've tried mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdn and dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdn bs=1M count=100 with no effect. I've also tried different HDD.
Can anybody here help me please?

You may need to remove the write-intent bitmap before reshaping the array, and re-add it afterwards.

Yes, I have read about that, but all the tutorials are saying that it is a problem with the --grow part and not while adding the drive. I cannot add it even as a spare
